# SUM Case Logic with Distinct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first post, so please be gentle :)

I have a couple of queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(h.USERID))
FROM MHGROUP.USERHISTORY h with (NOLOCK) 
JOIN MHGROUP.DOCUSERS u with (NOLOCK) on h.USERID = u.USERID
where h.CUSTOM2 = 'Work Web'
and h.ACTIONDATETIME >= GETUTCDATE()-30 
and u.LOGIN = 'y'
```

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(h.USERID))
FROM MHGROUP.USERHISTORY h with (NOLOCK) 
JOIN MHGROUP.DOCUSERS u with (NOLOCK) on h.USERID = u.USERID
where h.CUSTOM2 = 'OUTLOOK'
and h.ACTIONDATETIME >= GETUTCDATE()-30 
and u.LOGIN = 'y'
```

Now I've been asked to pull the data for the last year, so I thought I would use a case statement, but cannot figure out how to incorporate the distinct user part into the sum case statement....so I get huge numbers, obviously

```sql
Select 'Date' = format(h.ACTIONDATETIME, 'MMM yyyy')
, sum(CASE WHEN h.CUSTOM2 = 'Work Web' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WorkWeb
, sum(CASE WHEN h.CUSTOM2 = 'OUTLOOK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Outlook
, 'UserCount' = COUNT(DISTINCT(h.USERID))
From MHGROUP.USERHISTORY h with (NOLOCK) 
JOIN MHGROUP.DOCUSERS u with (NOLOCK) on h.USERID = u.USERID
where u.LOGIN = 'y'
and Year(h.ACTIONDATETIME)>2017
Group By Format(h.ACTIONDATETIME,'MMM yyyy')
```

What is returning is the following, which is a sum. I am looking for a distinct count for each way.

[image: too many users]

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could update your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This would include table definitions (DDL) and sample data in the form of actual insert statements along with expected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count(column)` does not count `null` values so you could use `count()` with a case statement that returns `h.USERID` or `null`.

```
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.CUSTOM2 = 'Work Web' THEN h.USERID ELSE NULL END) UserCountWorkWeb
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN h.CUSTOM2 = 'OUTLOOK' THEN h.USERID ELSE NULL END) UserCountOutlook
```

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is not necessary (but it makes the example more illustrative).

Comment: Awesome answer Mikael. Thanks so very much! You made my month!